# Windows 8 Metro localhost lookup

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, localhost

Is it possible to have Windows 8 Metro apps communicate with localhost (localhost/dir OR 127.0.0.1/dir) without running this command:

```
%windir%\system32\CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n=[packageid]
```

Without running the above, the app refuses to communicate with localhost through http/wcf. From my research I found that the script is currently the only work around? Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to?

Comment: a webAPI service. the problem is having the service hosted on the same machine as the client. I could connect to the service without any trouble from another computer for example

Comment: What is the error you are getting when trying to connect?

Comment: Have you tried adding an alias to the [HOSTS file](http://www.petri.co.il/edit-hosts-file-windows-8.htm)? I wonder how smart the filter is... Of course this is only possible when you have access to the system, and you could run the command instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your app will pass the certification and be listed in the MS Store if you try to communicate with another app via localhost.
As far as I know, all Metro apps must provide functionality regardless of other software that might be installed (or missing).

For more details check:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/0268dbe3-4ea9-4889-bc26-583ff2760708

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/0005b94f-8409-4804-88c5-e2f5fcce460a/

If it's the communication via localhost is for testing purposes only, it's OK.
But if you plan to submit it to Windows Store, maybe you should re-think your application.